# How to Scroll to Specific Row in UIPickerView In iOS Swift 3

Tags: swift3, uipickerview, uipicker, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

I have a `UIPickerView` with values 0...250. There is 2 Components in `UIPickerView`. In First component i am displaying these values. but i want to detect scrolling method of the `UIPickerView`. because when pickerView appears the value I would like to display is 75. means pickerView is scroll to row number 75. and user can scroll up and down the picker with values 0...250.
I have tried this code in `UIPickerView` `titleForRow row: Int` method

```
pickerView.selectRow(75, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

in this case when pickerView appears the selected value is 75. Below is exactly what i want

[image]

but the problem is that on scrolling `pickerView` my app crash with following error

`[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

anyone help me please thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

While inside the `viewDidLoad` method, your picker is empty. You can do this if you delay execution of the select call until after the data is finished loading. Likely one cycle will be enough.

You can add it in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`

Comment: i don't want to do this on `optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,inComponent component: Int)` i want to show 75 when `pickerView` appears

Comment: Ok for that you can use `pickerView.selectRow(75, inComponent: 0, animated: true)` But it might be your line in `viewdidLoad()`, try moving your `select` to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Can you please provide your code more here.. Bcz it seems might be datasource (your array)is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are scrolling to `index` 75 before the `pickerView` has initialised that `cell`. `UIPickerView` only initialises visible cells first, and initialise rest of the cells as you scroll.

Do this in `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    pickerView.selectRow(75, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```